# Public IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, public, instance-variables, iboutlet

I want to use an IBOutlet from classA on classB

Why is this not working?

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController {
           @public IBOutlet UILabel* myLabel;
           }
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel* myLabel;
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h" 
@implementation ClassB
           ClassA.myLabel.text =  @"Any String";
```

Xcode sends this error: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

Or, is there another way to do this? This problem is killing me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: When the compiler crashes, that's quite a serious problem. Make sure to file a bug: http://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy&paste this directly from XCode? Your code looks strange.
- ClassB.m should not contain the implementation of ClassA (this should go to ClassA.m)
- You probably don't want ClassA.myLabel.text, but instance_of_ClassA.myLabel.text

If this doesn't help, could you please provide some more information?

Comment: I just put the header of classA, and the implementation of classB. I want to use my outlet from classA on classB, but you're right... i can't do it without an instance of ClassA, thank you... i'll look another way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, that code looks like it was written by a C++ coder. Don't cross the streams. This is an ancient questions but I couldnt resist fixing such a basic error.

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController {}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* myLabel; // iVar is created for you by compiler
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h" 
@implementation ClassB
  -(void)youNeedToBeInsideAMethod {
    classAInstance.myLabel.text =  @"Genius!";
  }
@end
```

ObjectiveC != C++ or vice versa (of course there is always Objective C++)